# how to update each line in a file

Tags: perl, perl-module

i have file in that i have one line is like `{<pN_SLOT>,<pN_Port>}` ,user will give the value N for example N=9 ;then these lines should print 9 times in the file with increment of N value .
Example: input file contains one line like this `{<pN_SLOT>,<pN_Port>}` then in output file it should update like this `{<p0_SLOT>,<p0_Port>}`,`{<p1_SLOT>,<p1_Port>}`,`{<p2_SLOT>,<p2_Port>}`,...upto `{<p8_SLOT>,<p8_Port>}`  . 
if any perl module please suggest 
any help/idea will be appreciable thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $count = 9;
for my $num ( 0 .. $count ) {
    print "{<p${num}_SLOT>,<p${num}_Port>},\n";
}
```

If you're taking an input file, and wanting to replace 'N' with 'number', then what you need* is a regular expression:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $line = '{<pN_SLOT>,<pN_Port>}';
my $count = 9;
for my $num ( 0 .. $count ) {
    my $newline = ( $line =~ s/N/$num/gr ); 
    print "$newline\n";
}
```

The [`perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) page will give you some more regular expressions you can use to transform text.

As for reading in from files and numbers - this is actually the same problem. `STDIN` is a 'standard input' filehandle.

You can read from it with `<STDIN>`.

e.g.

```
print "Enter Number:\n"; 
my $response = <STDIN>; 
chomp ( $response ); #necessary, because otherwise it includes a linefeed.
```

Or for reading from a file on disk:

```
open ( my $input_file, "<", "your_file_name" ) or die $!; 
my $line = <$input_file>;  #note - reads just ONE LINE here. 
chomp ( $line ); 
close ( $input_file );
```

If you want to read more than one line in the second example, you may want to look at [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) and especially the `$/` operator.

* need is strong - perl usually has many ways to do things. So in this case - "need" means "I suggest as a course of action".